# how to edit adobe flash height and width

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-flash-cs3

i'm making an swf file that will load another swf file

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(myLoader);
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("1.swf");
myLoader.load(url);
```

i want to edit the main SWF dimensions to be same as the loaded one how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the stage dimensions with [Stage.stageWidth](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageWidth) and [Stage.stageHeight](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageHeight). You might also want to look at [Stage.scaleMode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode) as that affects how the stage's size is interpreted when displaying the flash movie inside a bigger container (or fullscreen).

Otherwise the main movie's size is determined by the actual displaying flash player (being in a browser, standalone or via AIR), so you cannot really change it after then movie is actually loaded. You might want to look at resizing `B` instead to fit the maximum displayed area of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var l:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(l);

l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);

l.load(new URLRequest("1.swf"));

function done(e:Event):void{
     l.width = this.width;
     l.height = this.height;
      // OR
     l.width = 100;
     l.height = 100;
}
```

this script will not help you if your flash is fullscreen and the user resizes the stage

Comment: hi 
thanks for your answer but you got it wrong
I have an SWF (( called A)) i want it load another SWF (( called B)) now i want A dimensions  to be same as B